# Google Charts custom data-point markers (images)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I was wondering if there is a way of defining custom images as data-point.

For a LineGraph there is a `pointSize` property which sets the size of data points. (Not surprisingly).

This property can also be overridden with the series property in which you can also define a custom color.

Nonetheless, I can't see anything that would allow custom markers.

To make my question absolutely clear:

This is what I am going for: [Image with an example](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/213/timelinewithpics.png/)

Two ideal solutions

1. Setting a property to a datapoint with class name and defining a picture for this class name in css. (to me it seems impossible since these are SVG graphics)
2. Adding an extra column with data-marker image source.

Although these seem perfect in theory I have no idea how to go about implementing them.

A less perfect solution could be extracting point position from SVG and using JavaScript to dynamically position divs with images (this seems very unelegant and prone to bugs)

Alternatively please recommend a js charting library that would be free and had support for such functionality.

**Edit:**

In the meantime I found a very good and quite inexpensive (60$ per website license) library that covers this functionality : [Highcharts library](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/) But the original question is still open.

Comment: you can use the `getChartLayoutInterface` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) to find the (x, y) location of the point and add the image manually -- see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771)