# How can I attach the image or icon on edge of google line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to line chart looks like below

[image]

or just image sequence chart is possible?

like this
[image]

is there any possible way for achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `getChartLayoutInterface` [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods)

```
var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
```

to find the (x, y) location of the point

```
var xPos = layout.getXLocation(data.getValue(row, xColumn));
var yPos = layout.getYLocation(data.getValue(row, yColumn));
```

then add the image manually and adjust accordingly

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colors: ['#000000'],
    legend: 'none',
    lineSize: 2
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var layout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      // add image above every fifth element
      if ((i % 5) === 0) {
        var xPos = layout.getXLocation(data.getValue(i, 0));
        var yPos = layout.getYLocation(data.getValue(i, 1));

        var whiteHat = container.appendChild(document.createElement('img'));
        whiteHat.src = 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/16/clone_old.png';
        whiteHat.className = 'whiteHat';

        // 16x16 (image size in this example)
        whiteHat.style.top = (yPos - 16) + 'px';
        whiteHat.style.left = (xPos) + 'px';
      }
    }
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.whiteHat {
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah It's very hopeful for me.
But the images and graph are shown separately when at least one element appears before graph. It seems image's coordinates are absolute not relative. Are you know the way to get left-top coordinates of container?

Comment: I solve the problem. I used jquery function which retrieve position of element. and recalculate position of images. Thanks for your help. have a nice day