# How can I put an SVG Image as Annontation in google chart tools using Angular and ng2-google-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

I want to create an Component which shows some Measurements and add some Annontation as Icons. 
I'm using Angular with ng2-google-charts for the chart. There is an example on https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#annotating-data for column role annontationText, I want to do the same with annontation.

But it I can not switch the annontation to html. But the way the example with annontationText will also not working for me. I don't know if that, error comes from the angular component, or if I have overseen something.

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-measurement',
  templateUrl: './measurement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./measurement.component.css']
})
export class MeasurementComponent implements OnInit {
  plot;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {
     this.createPlot('Test');
  }
  createPlot(title) {
    this.plot = {
      chartType: 'LineChart',
      options:
        {
          title: title,
          height: '600px',
          curveType: 'function',
          hAxis: {title: 'x'},
          vAxis: {  title: 'y' }
        },
      dataTable: [
        [ {  'id': 'x', 'label': 'x','type': 'number' },
          {  'id': 'y', 'label': 'y','type': 'number' },
          {'id': 'icon', 'label': 'icon', 'type': 'string', 'role': 'annotation', p: {html: true}} ],
        [0.0005, 1434,null],
        [0.001, 1436,null],
        [0.0015, 1435, '<img src="./assets/img/icon1.svg">'],
        [0.002, 1429, '<img src="./assets/img/ic_bench.svg">'],
        [0.0025, 1439, null]
        [0.003, 1451, null],
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

But it would not display the image but only the HTML text.

Comment: you'll have to use chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface` -- and place the images manually on the chart's `'ready'` event, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771)...